# "Everything I did were+the+plural noun" VS "Everything I did was+adjective"

Tags: grammaticality

> "Everything I did **were** the **things** possible for me to do."

VS

> "Everything I did **was** **wrong**."

Are both of them correct?

Comment: Although the first sentence might be used by some people, it's arguably ungrammatical. (Although not necessarily idiomatically wrong.) It would be better if it were rephrased. (1) ***All the things*** *I did **were** possible for me to do.* (2) *Everything I did **was** a possibility for me to do.*

Comment: @JasonBassford "Everything that he can do are the things that are possible for him to do, he can't do something impossible." Doesn't it sound correct?

Comment: As @JasonBassford points out, "Everything" **were** is not grammatical. Because, "every" takes the singular form, right? So that "Everything I did was wrong" is only grammatical here.

Comment: (I just realized I'd made a couple of typos in my previous comment that didn't make sense, so I'm writing it again—correctly.) No, it definitely doesn't sound right. Everything is a singular noun (*everything **is** right*, *everything **is** wrong*), so the single thing should make use of a singular verb or singular noun. *Everything …* ***is the thing*** is natural; but *everything …* ***are the things*** is not natural at all.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am not a native speaker, I can answer this at least.

As is [**in this page,**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/everyone-everybody-everything-everywhere) and at the comment line too,

> We use everyone, everybody, **everything** and everywhere **with** **singular verbs:**
>
> Everybody knows the truth.
>
> At night, with the lights shining on the water, everything looks different.
>
> We couldn’t get a seat. Everywhere **was** so crowded.

So your

> Are both of them correct?

is not correct. Only the second one is correct.

Thank you.